# Visual Studio 2015 freezes when adding a new Controller in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services

Every time I right click the Controller folder and click add -> Controller, VS 2015 freezes. I am running on the latest win 10, VS is up to date and all the packages are the latest. I've tried different locations, checking permissions on the files and all types of other fun stuff. The weird part is that it only freezes on an azure mobile services project. If I do a web api project or mvc project I can add the controller just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What add-ons/extensions do you have installed on Visual Studio?

Comment: Nothing. I did a fresh install of VS2015 community and tried running it with no add ons. Same thing. Really bizarre.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also was having this issue for a few days now and I just managed to solve it by re-installing the Entity Framework package using the nuget console:

***Update-Package EntityFramework -reinstall***

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I actually tried repairing the install of VS and that didn't help.

Comment: @Layinka could you give some detail so we could try to help you ?

Comment: This worked for me as well, Thanks! Make sure to use the -reinstall option otherwise it will update the EntityFramework package and all dependencies to the newest version.

Comment: Sorry for the "me too!", but this worked in my case.

Comment: it didn't work for me. still hangs when I click "add new controller". already wasted 2 hours of my time. should I charge my time to microsoft instead of my customer now?

Comment: I removed EntityFramework nuget, and started getting this issue, i installed it back. Everything works fine... I do not understand what is the link between entityframwork and adding new item to project...

Answer (score 3):

The above solution didn't solve my problem. Even reinstalling VS 2015 didn't.
But the running the following could solve my problem:

1. open administrative cmd in folder

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
2. `devenv.exe  /resetsettings`
3. `devenv.exe  /resetuserdata`

Comment: did it solve your problem or not? Please only post answers.

Comment: Worked for me! Cheers

Comment: Does not solve for me, I would like to speak to your supervisor!